# Best way to re-use large part of php code

Tags: php

I am working on custom template for CMS and I have to use quite big part of code over and over to display content, code itself remains the same. So I am thinking how better to optimize it:

1. Make it a function - would be perfect, but its using about half-hundred variables, I would have to re-declare them all as globals. Maybe there is a way to declare a function so that it wil have the parent variable scope?
2. I cannot use a cycle as this code repeats in different places without pattern
3. The best approach for me so far is to create a separate file and use include to place it, but creating separate file is not desirable as it is harder to understand and manage for end users, maybe it is possible to include code in the same file?

Edit:
For more clarification, template is that what renders html on page. So the code that I am working on just need to render different content several times in the same structure but with different content (code remains the same but variable change their value). So the workflow is:

- displaying some other unique content,
- displaying content which code in question generated,
- displaying some other unique content, without any pattern,
- displaying content which code in question generated again,
- and ability to insert it anywhere else on this page.

Is there any other method of re-using code other that those three mentioned above(and except unsing goto too)?

Comment: Reusable code == function. Period. That's what they're for. How to best write this with regards to variables necessary depends on the actual code in question.

Comment: You can go for the 3rd option also but use include_once whenever you include the separate file

This way if you ever want to make changes the template you have to make in single file and they will reflect across the site

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but include once, as far as I know will not allow to include same code again, and while its definitely must be when you include a functions, it just will not allow me to use rendering code again on same page? If I will make changes to file I have included, it will reflect changes anywhere is it? I don't remember file includes to be cached or something like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The best approach for me so far is to create a separate file and use include to place it, but creating separate file is not desirable as it is harder to understand and manage for end users, maybe it is possible to include code in the same file?

Without you providing any other details, this is the best approach. Also, when you say, “…but creating separate file is not desirable as it is harder to understand and manage for end users.” you are basically saying, “This client wanted something complex, but is not willing to pay for a true CMS solution & somehow now I am burdened with somehow simplifying an inherently complex process.”

This sounds like a classic client with supposedly “no budget” who wants you to do “great work” and then show the one person in the office who is a “tech” how to do things.

My advice?  Just do the 3rd scenario & don’t worry about the end users in a case like this.  You did your job.

Comment: Well I can provide a code, but I suppose it is useless, because it could be any part of any large view. And yes its mostly that kind of client, so this matter is not of big importance but I'm thought maybe I would learn some better way of reducing code I and anyone else could always use. Creating more files mostly makes it harder for anyone else to work with later as they will need to understand what each of them do, opposed to just "oh, here is a view".

Answer (score 1):

If you have about half-hundred variables for one function, your function/code is wrong :)

A function should be small, compact and flexible and should (in general) not be bigger than your screen. My avg function is about 20-50 lines tops.

Because you can use function in functions, you can reuse a lot of the code

Because you work on your CMS, define small parts that happen often. Like `getPage` or `getPageId` or `getFileContent`(if you want your own function for that). Those functions have only a hand full of parameters they need, so no need to global things.

Not sure how your code works, but in this example you could use the `getPage` and `getPageId` together:

```
function getPage( $url ){
    $pageId = getPageId($url);
    // and now get a page:
    $content = getPageContent($pageId);
    return $content;
}
```

You can use those functions now because they only perform small tasks. If properly done, small functions will create room for big functions to decrease in size. As you can see in my example, the function that gets the page is actually very slim!

Comment: I do not have a function, I just need to repeat again part of code in view, so making it a function was a logical suggestion, but its just large, I cannot reduce it, and I cannot modify controller to call it from there and just pass result into view.

Comment: I doubt the fact you cant make a function of some parts of your code. I cant think of a single valid reason for that :p I've been doing this for quite a while now, you can always break big code down in smaller functions. Even if this doesnt decrease the actual amount of lines of code, it gets a whole lot better for other people to read the code

Comment: Well, I actually can, but would it be worth of trouble? Controller passes to the view many variables. And if I make part of code a function, all variables are just remains out of it in the global scope. Sure I can declare them as globals but declaring a bunch of variables is just more of trouble compared to separating code into file and including it, so the variables have the same scope and don't need to be re-declared.